# Usage: fortune -P [-f] -a [xsz] Q: file [rKe9] -v6[+] file1

Tags: terminal, games

I have fortune-mod installed, giving me a nice little quote every time I open the terminal.

Today I came across this quote:

```
(computers)
%
Usage: fortune -P [-f] -a [xsz] Q: file [rKe9] -v6[+] file1 ...
```

As far as I know, the syntax shown does not seem like valid syntax for the `fortune` command (e.g. the `-P` switch is not referenced in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/6/fortune).

Is this a reference to some kind of esoteric joke?

Answer (score 2):

Fortune has been around for 40 years, under many guises. The quotes from which it makes a random selection are even older: some from Confucius, Socrates and others. Some version of fortune (possibly) had these options, but it is probably fake.

The joke here is along the lines of:

Q. What kind of day am I going to have?

A. Your commands won't work, and the documentation is going to baffle you, too.

In a similar vein, when my server was too busy for me to get any work done, I used to run a program that just put this (standard) message on every terminal:

"The system is temporarily unavailable."

to discourage other users from logging in.